# Timer not working for an automatic CarouselView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm making an automatic CarouselView (slider) to slide between images every x seconds. I know there are plenty of examples but none of them helped me to make mine work. So here is the deal:

This is my xaml page:

```
<CarouselView x:Name="carou_slideshow" Grid.Row="1" IsVisible="False">
       <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
       </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Whenever the user clicks on the button to start the slideshow, it shows my carousel with its images without any issue but it doesn't change the current image after x seconds. Here's how I've done it :

```
private void btn_slideShow_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   stk_header.IsVisible = false;
   stk_options.IsVisible = false;
   grid_images.IsVisible = false;
   carou_slideshow.IsVisible = true;

   carou_slideshow.ItemsSource = sources;
   Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (Func<bool>)(() =>
   {
       carou_slideshow.Position = (carou_slideshow.Position + 1) % sources.Count;
       return true;
   })
   );
}
```

Any idea why ?

EDIT : I realized that in my project I already had a timer in the same class. After removing it and keeping the one in the button method, my application crashes without any error.

EDIT2 : Someone gave me a solution on this post and deleted it after. I tried it and it doesn't work for me.. As I was sure it would, I tried to increment something else and the timer works perfectly fine, but the image doesn't swipe. Also, it can randomly close the application as well as not having any issue.

Comment: what is the purpose of `% sources.Count;`?  Why don't you just increment the `Position`?

Comment: @Jason Incrementing the position doesn't work too. It doesn't slide between the images. The purpose of `% sources.Count;` is to know when the list ends so it won't get out of index.

Comment: ok, that's pretty clever.  Are you sure your timer is firing?  Have you tried using a System.Timers.Timer instead?  Are you sure you are updating on the UI thread?

Comment: @Jason Yes I am. When debugging the application goes in the timer code. I've just tried to use System.Timers.Timer but I doesn't do anything either. Maybe I've done it in the wrong way ? How can I check if it's correctly updating in the UI thread ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/main-thread

Comment: @Jason It is updating in my UI Thread. Do you have other ideas of why my app crashes (without giving error) ? I edited my question, please read the extra comment at the end of it and if you have any solution, I'll be pleased to try.

Comment: Which line is causing the crash?  Have you tried to catch the exception?

Comment: @Jason It doesn't give any exception. It just closes up my application.

Comment: What does the log show?  If you put a breakpoint in the page and step through it can you determine which line is the cause?

Comment: @Jaon I've noticed something. It doesn't always close up. There is a small chance for the application to run "normally" but even though it does it doesn't slide automatically. After re-trying to debug and putting it only on the timer, I see that the application goes several times on the timer before doing the code in it. The application doesn't seem to crash/close if the debug is only focused on the timer part. What are you thought on that ?